# Sources that Parah Adumah shows love between Bnei Yisrael and Hashem

Tags: sources-mekorot, chukas, love, parah-adumah

I'm looking for sources that Parah Adumah shows love between Bnei Yisrael and Hashem.

(I know that there are recent sources that say this. I'm looking for earlier sources, preferably Rishonim or earlier. The best I have so far is [Tosfos in Avoda Zarah 35a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Avodah_Zarah.35a.7.1?vhe=WikiSource_Tosafot&lang=bi)

> תוס עבודה זרה לה. ד"ה מאי שנא האי קרא דשייליה - ואומר מורי הר"ר אלחנן שזהו מה שיסד הקליר בפרשת פרה אדומה אין להרהר על מה נחקקה שכולם נתנו בנשיקה.

but it's not a great source because it seems from Tosfos that the point is silence, not love.)

Comment: How do you know that neshikah means love? Maybe it is a reference to neshikah as in misas neshikah?

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Its clear from context in Tosfos if you see the whole thing inside that its not talking about Missas Neshikah.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean it's talking about misas neshikah. I just meant that considering the unknown mekor of the paytan, it comes to mind that neshikah here may refer to a sweetening of the Jewish relationship to misah generally.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Okay, sorry about the confusion. I added the hyperlink to the Tosfos. I don't think that's what Tosfos is saying either, but take a look at it in its entirety and see what you think. Thanks so much.

Comment: Tosafos seems to be talking about the סוד of all the mitzvos, not specifically Parah Adumah?